# Стать профессионалом

Tags: работа

Кому-то этот вопрос может показаться глупым, но для меня это актуально.Мне 19 лет, учусь на 3 курсе факультета компьютерного интеллекта. Естественно , учат нас только основам.

Собственно вопрос: как же стать профессиональным программистом? На что делать упор в изучении? Сколько выделять времени на программирование без ущерба для стипендии?  С чего начинать  в изучении языков пр.? Все ваши советы будут для меня интересными и возможно помогут мне на этом нелегком пути.

**UPD** Душа лежит к GameDev, но поскольку найти работу в этом сфере довольно-таки непросто, интересует еще и  веб-разработка.

Comment: Уточните - какая именно сфера программирования вас интересует, иначе вы получите абстрактные ответы, которые, по сути, не будут так хороши как могли бы быть

Comment: Быстро напишите все курсовые (с программированием) всем отстающим (ленивым) на всех курсах факультета.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

найти работу в этом сфере довольно-таки непросто???

Не скажу что элементарно, так-же "непросто" как и найти хорошую работу в любой другой IT сфере.

Кстати, если лежит душа к GameDev - топаете на [форум GameDev.ru](http://gamedev.ru/forum), создаете тему - "программист ищет команду" где описываете свои навыки, опыт, пожелания, свободное время и т.д.

Вливаетесь в команду разработчиков, решаете реальный задачи разработчиков игр, глубже изучаете специфику, реализовываете реальный проэкт(редко что доводится до конца, но шансы есть). Спустя N времени понимаете что вы уже чего-то да стоите, убеждаетесь в том что gamedev это действительно то чего вы хотите (или не то, тогда думаете - что именно вас интересует), вот тогда уже и стоит заниматься поиском работы.

Скажу лишь что в наше время, во всем мире огромный дифицит разработчиков (в том числе, естественно и в геймдеве), высококвалифицированных и грамотных разработчиков еще меньше. А высококвалифицированных, грамотных и само-обучаемых, целеустремленных, держащих себя в курсе развития технологий и инструментов вообще единицы.

Причем, как не странно (спс образовательной системе, справедливо, наверное, для всего СНГ) - в СНГ он еще более заметен, причем в будущем дефицит будет только обострятся. Что дает любому неплохому, любящему свое дело разработчику 2 очень важные вещи, а именно:

- легче найти первую работу
- возможность быстрого карьерного роста

Вот собственно ответ в стиле **what to do**, насколько я понял именно такой ответ вы и хотели увидеть

Comment: Добавлю: Попутно, пока есть время, налегайте на изучение английского.

Comment: Если начнет решать реальный проблемы разработчиков игр, английский "выучиться сам по себе" xD

Answer (score 3):

Стать профессионалом очень просто - для этого достаточно начать зарабатывать на жизнь своей профессией :)

Comment: это не всем дается) деньги не решают вопросы профессионализма) - не панацея точно

Comment: профессионал - тот кто работает по профессии, если ты дворник, а ночами прогаешь, то ты возможно профессиональный дворник, но не профессиональный программист, хотя и ломаешь сайты пентагона =)

Comment: Где я сказал, что деньги решают вопросы профессионализма? 

Я лишь хотел сказать, что профессионал - это не тот кто может пяткой левой ноги за полвечера на [brainfuck'e](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brainfuck) операционку написать, а тот, у кого основным заработком в жизни является работа по профессии.

Answer (score 1):

Взять какой-то язык или сферу информатики, которые Вам больше всего нравятся, и вгрызаться в него. Взять учебники, читать и параллельно писать программы. Добившись какого-то уровня, попытаться найти работу по этому направлению, можно даже и не очень высокооплачиваемую. И упорно грызть гранит знаний. Конечно, желательно, чтобы направление было востребованное и перспективное. Как при этом не нанести вреда учебе, смотрите сами, какую пропорцию соблюсти, по своим способностям и возможностям.

Answer (score 0):

Посоветую найти работу по профессии на пол ставки, тогда и опыта наберешься много и приобретешь навык работы в коллективе. Если не такой возможности значит самосовершенствуйся дома, придумывай себе задачи и решай их.

Comment: ответа на вопрос "как стать профессионалом" - нет.

То что написали вы справедливо для начинающих разработчиков, не более

Comment: А сразу профессионалом ты не станешь, всегда нужно начинать с малого

Comment: Насколько я понимаю вопросы такого рода подразумевают то, что уже начал...

Answer (score 0):

как по мне вопрос реально глупый, потому что на 3 курсе, это больше похоже на поиск отмазки, что бы нечего не делать, поиск такой себе идеальной формулы образования, а может какое-то самостимулирование. Это не важно в общем, потому что особо не вникая во все подробности, если ты сможешь ответить на пару вопросов, типа, "а что ты уже умеешь делать?", "умеешь ли ты программировать вообще?", "что ты знаешь про ИИ и где оно может пригодится, где и кому?".. ну и еще пару таких, тогда сможешь ответить и на свой вопрос, и сколько времени тратить на программирование и на какой язык и когда придет время считать себя профессиональным программистом

Comment: Отмазку не ищу, наоборот же, пытаюсь оптимизировать свои старания в этом направлении)

Comment: обычно оптимизируют, то что уже работает =) а не то что собирается как-то начать работать =). Тебе или надо отходить от специальности факультета и учить что-то востребованное, типа джавы, или развиваться дальше в ИИ и писать на плюсах и может когда-то получится устроится в гейм-девелоперскую крутую фирму и делать, там продвинутых мобов =)

Comment: На факультете компьютерного интеллекта не изучают только ИИ)) Специальность у меня "Компьютерные науки".

Answer (score 0):

как стать профи?? - начните хотя бы двигаться, а то дуть в парус стоящей лодки - глупо, а когда лодка поплывет, ей уже удобнее управлять)да и стать профи это понятие абстрактное, мне кажетс, как только вы скажите - я профи, вы проиграли.....надо постоянно себя теребить и ставить цели и задачи, постоянно учиться - ИТ это не область для лентяя или человека не жаждущего или не любящего процесс познания и образования себя)

Comment: ИТ это не область для лентяя или человека не жаждущего или не любящего процесс познания и образования себя)

Скажите это большей половине ИТ :DDD

Comment: потому некоторые и отличают прогера от кодера, а нелюбители этого дела долго не задерживаются в этой области =(

Comment: Быдлокодер тоже может быть любителем своего дела :D

Comment: как показывает практика, такие или уходят от программирования или идут работать и там их отучивают =)

Comment: Крайне радужная у вас практика... Моя показывает абсолютно противоположное.

Answer (score 0):

Хоспади. Мне бы ваш возраст и факультет компьютерного интеллекта. Учите математику (мат анализ), моделирование процессов, теорию искусственного интеллекта, способы прогнозирования экономических процессов. Делаете работу, которая находить реальное применение в экономике/спекулятивной торговле ценными бумагами/валютой. Тратите несколько лет своей жизни на безумную идею, и в случае удачи получаете некислый профитв виде работы на мегабогатого дядечку с годовой ЗП под лям баксов/ойро.
По мне так игра стоит свеч. И знаю не по наслышке.